# how can I add people to my Brand Account over api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have the access token of a youtube Brand Account owner. With this token I would like to add other people (as admin) to this account over API.

This operation is possible manually (info : https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007?hl=en), but I didn't see anything about user management on youtube-data api.

is this operation is impossible over API or am I looking at the wrong google API documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the YouTube v3 Data API supports this operation :(. The only other APIs are analytics and reporting.

For a complete list of what the Data API can do check out this link:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the current YouTube API. If this operation is manually possible over webpages, you can simply write a program (e.g. `nodejs` application) to execute the steps needed, automatically.